# How to transform List to Characters Array?

Tags: java

I have `List<String> actualRacers` that contains some information of the racers.

I tried to do like this :

```
   List<String> actualRacers = loadRacerListFromFile("racers.txt");
   Character[] expectedRacers = new Character[actualRacers.size()];
   expectedRacers = actualRacers.toArray(expectedRacers);
```

but I catch `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` in this line : `expectedRacers = expectedRacersOutput.toArray(expectedRacers);`

LoadRacersListFromFile :

```
 private List<String> loadRacerListFromFile(String fileName) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResource(fileName).toURI());

    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
        return lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `loadRacerListFromFile` and `expectedRacersOutput`?

Comment: @YCF_L Edit It.

Comment: What version of `JAVA` are you using?

Comment: @Anatolii Java 8

Comment: what is expectedRacersOutput?

Comment: try with char[] chars = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray(); instead  of actualRacers.toArray(expectedRacers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please replace  `actualRacers.toArray(expectedRacers)` with

```
char[] chars = list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
List<String> actualRacers = loadRacerListFromFile("racers.txt");
Object[] expectedRacers = actualRacers.toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to do the following:

```
Character[] chars = list.toArray(Character[]::new);
```

But the if I needed convert to a `primitive array`
I would just do it in
a loop. If I needed to do it often
I would write a method.

```
     char[] chars = new char[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
           chars[i] = list.get(i);
     }
```

Streams are a great tool but they aren't a panacea for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `String.join` to convert list into `char` array

```
char[] array = String.join("", actualRacers).toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this line of code

```
String.join("", actualRacers ).toCharArray()
```